# Twilio Node.js - Creating Conference Participant with statusCallback

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to add a participant to an existing conference. It works just fine, but now I want to add a statusCallback to be called when the ringing begins for the new participant.

Here's the line where I'm creating the new participant:

```
client.conferences(conferenceName).participants.create({
  from: `client:${fromAgentId}`,
  to: `client:${toAgentId}`,
  statusCallback: statusCallbackUrl,
  statusCallbackEvent: "initiated ringing answered completed",
  statusCallbackMethod: "POST",
});
```

As I said, the new participant is successfully getting added to the conference, but the statusCallbackUrl never gets called.

According to these docs https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant?code-language=Node.js#parameters-1 it looks like the `participants.create()` method should accept a statusCallback, so I have no idea why it's not working. If anyone has an idea, I'd love to hear from you.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here.

It seems like it's a problem with the Twilio docs. Regarding the `statusCallbackEvent` parameter, the docs state:

> Can be: initiated, ringing, answered, and completed. Separate multiple values with a space.

However, rather than separating multiple values with a space, the `statusCallbackEvent` parameter should be an array of values.